# Qt doesnt create directory on msvc2010 release

Tags: qt, release, visual-studio-2010

I am using Qdir mkpath(dir) and QImage::save to save .png images. But on release mode the program doesnt create folders nor save images even though it does on debug.

I am using Qt 4.8.2 for release qmain.lib, QtCore4.lib, QtGui4.lib and with qmaind.lib, QtCored4.lib, QtGuid4.lib on debug

Could you please help me to fix this ?

Comment: Are you running the release version in the same dir as the debug one? Is the path you are creating absolute or does it assume some subdir that's only in the debug directory

Comment: Yes, I am running them in the same dir. The path is also absolute. I am creating directory in the folder in my desktop. But the point is that I am using function to create folder and it creates some and it doesn't create some. I am also checking if the directory is created.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out what was wrong. If you are using assert you should drop NDEBUG from Release - Preprocessor options =)